# Sniffing Bluetooth Packets

Tags: bluetooth, rf, hardware

I'm attempting to create something similar in nature to the [Ubertooth one](http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net). I'd like to sniff Bluetooth packets using the Arduino.

I've found a few nRF24L01+ wireless modules, which appear to operate on a frequency similar to Bluetooth LE. Unfortunately, I don't believe this will work for Bluetooth or BLE.

What would be the best way to sniff radio frequencies in the Bluetooth range from Arduino, am I on the right track?

Comment: You'd need access to the raw data in the 2.4 ghz spectrum. The arduino just isn't fast enough for that. You could use dedicated hardware like the Ubertooth, or you could connect a [Software Defined Radio](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/about-rtl-sdr/) to your PC.  People are using a $20,- DVB-T TV tuner dongle based on the RTL2832U chipset for that.

Comment: Depending on what sorts of data you want to see (ie the more public parts before private ones are negotiated, if they even are in the cases of interest), you may be able to simply use a bluetooth or BLE chip.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm interested in the entire protocol, including the pairing proccess.